# ng-repeat passing index value to a function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click

I need to pass a $index value of a specific  element, added with ng-repeat, to a javascript function.
My code sample:

```
<tr ng-repeat="cells in CouponsList.CellPhones">
<td><button  ng-click="doStuff($index+1)">{{cells.localVendorAddress}}</button></td>
```

Now I am adding several buttons and when a specific button is pressed I need to send it's specific $index to the doStuff($index) function.
Any idea?

Comment: Hum… what?! What doesn't work with your current code?

Comment: The problem is that when I press the button it doesn't even go to the function, and do not pass the $index.

Comment: Add a plunker/jsfiddle showcasing the problem.

Comment: I'm guessing `doStuff()` is not on the scope.

Answer (score 8):

please see here : http://jsbin.com/yeweh/4/edit

```
<a href="" ng-repeat="s in students" ng-click="doit($index)">{{s.name}} - {{s.class}} </a>


var app = angular.module('app', []);



app.controller('firstCtrl', function($scope){

  $scope.doit= function(index){
    alert(index)

  }

  $scope.students = [
           {name: 'Aa_Student', class: 'A_Class'},
           {name: 'Ab_Student', class: 'A_Class'},
           {name: 'Ac_Student', class: 'B_Class'},
           {name: 'Ba_Student', class: 'B_Class'},
           {name: 'Bb_Student', class: 'C_Class'},
           {name: 'Bc_Student', class: 'C_Class'}];
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example.

http://jsfiddle.net/bdmRs/

What you have there looks ok but you might be missing something with the function definition for doStuff. It must be defined on the $scope like this:

```
$scope.doStuff = function(idx){
    alert(idx);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure when you're using ng-click that the function that is called is declared on the scope in the controller.

Therefore, if your function name is doStuff(index), you should see this defined somewhere in your code as (the below makes assumptions about your module and controller names):

```
var app = angular.module("MyModule", []);
app.controller("MyController", function($scope){

    $scope.doStuff = function(index){
        ... 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

KBE,

it seems that your function `doStuff` is not declared in your JS file with `$scope.doStuff`. In term of using the `$index` the syntax looks correct