# Getting undefined value for $index in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a button code block in jsp below which will pass $index of a selected checkbox to a javascript function in controller js which is defined on $scope. But when i try to print the $index on console i am getting undefined value for $index.

Code in Jsp

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning"
                        ng-disabled='validCheckbox'
                        **ng-click="addTemplate($index)">**
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>&nbsp;Add Middle
     </button>
```

Code in Js.

```
 $scope.addTemplate = function(index){
         console.log("index"+index);
```

Comment: `$index` is a special property of the [ngRepeat scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat). If you're not inside an `ngRepeat`, there's no `$index`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$index` only in `ng-repeat` in angular.js. Here is an example of how to use `$index`.
Let say you have `StringArray=['a','b','c'];`

```
<div ng-repeat="c in StringArray">
      <label>{{$index}}</label>
</div>
```

The result is :`0, 1, 2`

Comment: Does this answer your question, check the link below?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24873335/ng-repeat-passing-index-value-to-a-function